# How to enable the libattr frature(abbreviated xattr) in linux?

Tags: linux, python

I would use xattr in python, but found the xattr's keys() is empty, does that indicate the libattr feature wasn't enabled? I've learned the libattr feature is disabled in ext3/ext4 by default, but how to enable it? Expect your help! Thank you~

```
>>> import xattr
>>> x = xattr.xattr('tiger_8a428_userdvd.dmg')
>>> x
<xattr file='tiger_8a428_userdvd.dmg'>
>>> x.keys()
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `user_xattr` to the mount options for the filesystem in `/etc/fstab`.

Something like:

```
UUID=b1ab1ab1-ab1a-b1ab-1ab1-ab1ab1ab1ab1  /  ext3  user_xattr,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0  1
```